# Java process to return non-zero exit code reliably on errors

Tags: java

[In practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/why-does-java-exit-with-success-after-an-uncaught-exception) when java main method stops execution with unhandled exception, exit status is still 0, unless you wrap exception with try-catch and call System.exit explicitly with desired exit code.
But what if exception happens in class or static initializer and you newer reach main method, is there a way to return non-zero exit code reliably?

Comment: Maybe that's old (faulty) behavior. My test of an uncaught exception returns with -1.

Comment: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)` will return `1` when the main method or the static initializer fails with an exception. Please edit your question so it contains the source code you are running for testing and the specific java runtime you are using (and on which host).